# Trying to create RDF graph and get TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, rdf, semantic-web, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to create RDF graph using graph serialization in python.

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib import URIRef, BNode, Literal

...some code for cleaning data...

g = Graph()

def CreateRDF( base, s, p, o, t ):
    subject = URIRef(base + "/" + s)
    objectType = URIRef(base)
    predicate = URIRef(objectType + "#" + p)
    objects = Literal(o)
    col_type = t

    if 'text' in col_type:
        g.add( (subject, predicate, Literal(o, datatype=XSD.string) ) )
    elif 'varchar' in col_type:
        g.add( (subject, predicate, Literal(o, datatype=XSD.string) ) )
    elif 'int' in col_type: 
        g.add( (subject, predicate, Literal(o, datatype=XSD.int) ) )
    elif 'year' in col_type: 
        g.add( (subject, predicate, Literal(o, datatype=XSD.gYear) ) )
    else :
        g.add( (subject, predicate, objects ) )

    g.add( (subject, RDF.type, objectType) )

CreateRDF(base, subject, predicate, objects, column_type)

print("Creating file . . .")
print(g.serialize(format='turtle'))
```

I used turtle format as my RDF form. But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I'm not trying to compare anything between the data. I also already clean up the data by removing `null`, `0`, `>`, `<`, etc. But the RDFLib still assumes that i am trying to compare between the data. What i don't understand is, my data type is string. What should I do to fix this? Thanks

PS: My data are in SQL format and here i used DataFrame.

Comment: I would start by showing the whole code and data? without no way

Comment: I cannot show the the data because they're classified. But I'll show a piece of code by editing my question.

Comment: @AKSW I just edited my question

Comment: Assuming that there are problems  data, divide your data into two parts, then divide problematic part into two parts etc.

Comment: i just followed you suggestion. But I still cannot find which data that cause the error. @StanislavKralin